# Importance of ordering in Eigenvalues

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a matrix I want to find the eigenvalues of:

```
A = [
        [ .1, .17, 0, 0,    0,    0], 
        [.17,  .1, 0, 0,    0,    0], 
        [  0,   0, 0, 0,    0,    0], 
        [  0,   0, 0, 0,    0,    0], 
        [  0,   0, 0, 0,  1.2, 0.66], 
        [  0,   0, 0, 0, 0.66,  1.2],
]
```

I can find unordered eigenvalues with:

```
from numpy import linalg as LA
LA.eig(np.array(A))
```

output:

```
(array([ 0.27, -0.07,  1.86,  0.54,  0.  ,  0.  ]),
 array([[ 0.70710678, -0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , 0. ],
        [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , 0. ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        , 0. ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , 1. ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678, -0.70710678,  0.        , 0. ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.70710678,  0.        , 0. ]]))
```

Is the order of these lists important? As long as they are re-indexed together, would a change in order result in me losing information about the system?

Then also, I would naively expect the eigenvalues to be ordered in a way somewhat like `[ 0.27, -0.07,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.86,  0.54]`, reflecting how the two central columns and rows in the matrix are filled with zeroes - is this incorrect? Has re-ordering already, secretly, occurred in the example above?

Answer (score 0):

the order of eigen values is correct. according to the documentation. `np.linalg.ein()` returns two arrays

```
A = [
        [ .1, .17, 0, 0,    0,    0], 
        [.17,  .1, 0, 0,    0,    0], 
        [  0,   0, 0, 0,    0,    0], 
        [  0,   0, 0, 0,    0,    0], 
        [  0,   0, 0, 0,  1.2, 0.66], 
        [  0,   0, 0, 0, 0.66,  1.2],
]

A = np.array(A)

W, V = np.linalg.eig(A)
```

`W` contains eigen values and `V` contains eigen vectors such that `W[i]` is eigen value of `V[:, i]`

observe that `V[:, i]` is an eigen vector not `V[i]` which means `V` contains column vectors so..

```
A @ V[:, i] == W[i] * V[:, i]   # not V[i] @ A
```

having zero columns or rows in your transformation matrix `A` doesn't mean the corresponding eigen values in `W` will be or should be `0`. `W` and `V` don't follow any particular order, their order only makes sense when taken together.

the last two `0`s in `W` don't make sense with respect to to their indices. They only make sense if we look at the corresponding vectors in `V`.

```
V[:, -2:]

>>> [[0., 0.],
     [0., 0.],
     [1., 0.],
     [0., 1.],
     [0., 0.],
     [0., 0.]]
```

The last two vectors in `V` are third and fourth unit-basis vectors. with this we can conclude that the transformation matrix `A` will reduce any vector lying on the span of these basis vectors to a null vector. aka scale it by `0`